# How to examine and invoke the functions in Python's __main__ module from a different module

Tags: python, reflection

In Python, is it possible for a function in a module to examine the list of functions in `__main__` then execute functions that match a pattern?

For example, can I write a module that contains the function `run_all_auto` that will examine the list of functions in `__main__` then invoke all the functions that begin with `auto_`?

Yes, I know this task would be much easier/better if I put my `auto_` functions in a class; but, I'm just curious if it's possible to do so without "bundling" them somehow.

I see that I could add a parameter and do something like `my_module.run_all_auto(dir())`; but that only provides a list of function names, I don't see how to then invoke any of the functions.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "in `__main__`"?  Do you mean `if __name__ == '__main__'`?

Comment: I mean the functions in the python file that is the starting point for execution (e.g., `my_program.py` when I run `python my_program.py`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can access that as a module object anywhere (even within the `__main__` module itself) using:

```
sys.modules["__main__"]
```

So something like,

```
import sys

def run_all_auto():
    for name, attribute in vars(sys.modules['__main__']).items():
        if name.startswith("auto_"):
            attribute()
```